# I'm trying to list all NESTED values of an array in javascript, but get only the 1st value of each in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, template-literals

I am a newbe at Template Literals, mapping and javascript. I have an array and I'm using Template Literals to insert a div into an html. I'm mapping the array of 4 albums. In the array I have lists of tracks for each album. I'm trying to list one track list for each album at a time. When I run the code I only get the 1st track of each album instead of the 1st track list of the 1st album. How can I list all the values in the first nest of the array? The code is as follows:

```js
// JavaScript Document

var albumData =[
 { 
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx1.png",
  "artist": "Gen1artist",
  "name": "Gen1name",
  "release":"released 2017",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": "1",
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen1Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"2:47"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 2,
   "song":"Gen1Track2",
   "duration":"0:00"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 3,
   "link":"media/ffile_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen1Track3",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"2:52"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 4,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen1Track4",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"3:25"
  }

  ]
 },
 {
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx2.png",
  "artist": "Gen2artist",
  "name": "Gen2name",
  "release":"released 201x",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": 1,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen2Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"4:15"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 2,
   "song":"Gen2Track2",
   "duration":"3:22"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 3,
   "song":"Gen2Track3",
   "duration":"3:13"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 4,
   "song":"Gen2Track4",
   "duration":"5:01"
  }
  ]
 },
 {
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx3.png",
  "artist": "Gen3artist",
  "name": "Gen3name",
  "release":"released 2014",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": 1,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen3Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"4:04"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 2,
   "song":"Gen3Track2",
   "duration":"0:00"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 3,
   "song":"Gen3Track3",
   "duration":"0:00"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 4,
   "song":"Gen3Track4",
   "duration":"0:00"
  }

  ]
 },
 {
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx4.png",
  "artist": "Gen4artist",
  "name": "Gen4name",
  "release":"released 2006",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": 1,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen4Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"3:03"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 2,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen4Track2",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"4:36"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 3,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen4Track3",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"2:52"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 4,
   "song":"Gen4Track4",
   "duration":"0:00"
  }
  ]
 }
]
var songlist=$(`${albumData.map(function(songs) {
   for (var a in songs.tracks) {
          return `
     <li class="songlist">
    <span class="songs">${songs.tracks[a].TrackNumber + ".&nbsp;" + songs.tracks[a].song}</span>
    <span class="time">${songs.tracks[a].duration}</span>
   </li>
   `}
   }).join('')
}`)
var playlist=$('#playlist');
$( playlist ).append( songlist );
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#000000;
}
#playlist{
 float:right;
 width:60%;
 padding:10px;
   background-color:#373636;
 border:dashed #F7060A;
}
.tracklist{
 margin:5px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.songs{
 float:left;
}
.time{
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>playlist12-29.1</title>
<link href="mus_css/playlist12-29.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
        <div id="playlist">
        <!---<li class="tracklist">
    <span class="songs"></span>
    <span class="time"></span>
   </li>--->
        </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="mus_js/playlist12-29.1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a `return` statement inside your `foreach` loop. So that will return the first value enumerated in foreach. Instead you should use another map to generate a list from `tracks` array like below

```js
var songlist = $(`${albumData.map(function(songs) {
            return songs.tracks.map(r=>`
      <li class="tacklist">
                <span class="songs">${r.TrackNumber + ".&nbsp;" + r.song}</span>
                <span class="time">${r.duration}</span>
            </li>
      `).join('');
      }).join('')
}`);
```

```js
// JavaScript Document

var albumData = [{
    "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx1.png",
    "artist": "Gen1artist",
    "name": "Gen1name",
    "release": "released 2017",
    "tracks": [{
        "TrackNumber": "1",
        "link": "media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
        "song": "Gen1Track1",
        "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
        "duration": "2:47"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 2,
        "song": "Gen1Track2",
        "duration": "0:00"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 3,
        "link": "media/ffile_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
        "song": "Gen1Track3",
        "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
        "duration": "2:52"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 4,
        "link": "media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
        "song": "Gen1Track4",
        "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
        "duration": "3:25"
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx2.png",
    "artist": "Gen2artist",
    "name": "Gen2name",
    "release": "released 201x",
    "tracks": [{
        "TrackNumber": 1,
        "link": "media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
        "song": "Gen2Track1",
        "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
        "duration": "4:15"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 2,
        "song": "Gen2Track2",
        "duration": "3:22"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 3,
        "song": "Gen2Track3",
        "duration": "3:13"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 4,
        "song": "Gen2Track4",
        "duration": "5:01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx3.png",
    "artist": "Gen3artist",
    "name": "Gen3name",
    "release": "released 2014",
    "tracks": [{
        "TrackNumber": 1,
        "link": "media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
        "song": "Gen3Track1",
        "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
        "duration": "4:04"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 2,
        "song": "Gen3Track2",
        "duration": "0:00"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 3,
        "song": "Gen3Track3",
        "duration": "0:00"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 4,
        "song": "Gen3Track4",
        "duration": "0:00"
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx4.png",
    "artist": "Gen4artist",
    "name": "Gen4name",
    "release": "released 2006",
    "tracks": [{
        "TrackNumber": 1,
        "link": "media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
        "song": "Gen4Track1",
        "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
        "duration": "3:03"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 2,
        "link": "media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
        "song": "Gen4Track2",
        "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
        "duration": "4:36"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 3,
        "link": "media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
        "song": "Gen4Track3",
        "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
        "duration": "2:52"
      },
      {
        "TrackNumber": 4,
        "song": "Gen4Track4",
        "duration": "0:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
var songlist = $(`${albumData.map(function(songs) {
   return songs.tracks.map(r=>`
      <li class="tracklist">
 
    <span class="songs">${r.TrackNumber + ".&nbsp;" + r.song}</span>
    <span class="time">${r.duration}</span>
       
   </li>
      `).join('');
   }).join('')
}`);
var playlist = $('#playlist');
$(playlist).append(songlist);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#playlist {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #373636;
  border: dashed #F7060A;
}

.tracklist {
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  clear: both;
}

.songs {
  float: left;
}

.time {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>playlist12-29.1</title>
  <link href="mus_css/playlist12-29.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="playlist">
    <!---<li class="tracklist">
    <span class="songs"></span>
    <span class="time"></span>
   </li>--->
  </ul>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mus_js/playlist12-29.1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit:** Those bullets you see normally places at the beginning of an unordered list item. Why you see them in the middle? Because you use styles `float:left , float right` kind of styles it changes the placement of the bullet. What you can do about it is :

```css
.tracklist {
      margin: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      list-style: none; /* remove bullets */
      clear: both; /* fix floating so next item should place correctly*/
}
```

Comment: wow! I would have never figured that out. Thanks so much! now I need to make the list style none.

Comment: one question though is why are there bullets between the song and time?

Answer (score 0):

The `return` inside the function passed to `map()` is "short-circuiting" the for loop. Here is a version that works with a for loop. It constructs the return value, then returns the value after the for loop is completed:

```
var songlist = albumData.map(function(songs) {
    let value = ''
    for (var a in songs.tracks) {
        value +=
            `<li class="songlist">
                 <span class="songs">${songs.tracks[a].TrackNumber + ".&nbsp;" + songs.tracks[a].song}</span>
                 <span class="time">${songs.tracks[a].duration}</span>
            </li>`
    }
    return value;
});
```

```js
// JavaScript Document

var albumData =[
 { 
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx1.png",
  "artist": "Gen1artist",
  "name": "Gen1name",
  "release":"released 2017",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": "1",
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen1Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"2:47"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 2,
   "song":"Gen1Track2",
   "duration":"0:00"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 3,
   "link":"media/ffile_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen1Track3",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"2:52"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 4,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen1Track4",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"3:25"
  }

  ]
 },
 {
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx2.png",
  "artist": "Gen2artist",
  "name": "Gen2name",
  "release":"released 201x",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": 1,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen2Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"4:15"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 2,
   "song":"Gen2Track2",
   "duration":"3:22"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 3,
   "song":"Gen2Track3",
   "duration":"3:13"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 4,
   "song":"Gen2Track4",
   "duration":"5:01"
  }
  ]
 },
 {
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx3.png",
  "artist": "Gen3artist",
  "name": "Gen3name",
  "release":"released 2014",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": 1,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen3Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"4:04"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 2,
   "song":"Gen3Track2",
   "duration":"0:00"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 3,
   "song":"Gen3Track3",
   "duration":"0:00"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 4,
   "song":"Gen3Track4",
   "duration":"0:00"
  }

  ]
 },
 {
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx4.png",
  "artist": "Gen4artist",
  "name": "Gen4name",
  "release":"released 2006",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": 1,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen4Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"3:03"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 2,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen4Track2",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"4:36"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 3,
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":"Gen4Track3",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"2:52"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": 4,
   "song":"Gen4Track4",
   "duration":"0:00"
  }
  ]
 }
]
var songlist=albumData.map(function(songs) {
    let value = ''
  for (var a in songs.tracks) {
        value +=
            `<li class="songlist">
            <span class="songs">${songs.tracks[a].TrackNumber + ".&nbsp;" + songs.tracks[a].song}</span>
            <span class="time">${songs.tracks[a].duration}</span>
            </li>`
    }
    return value;
});
var playlist=$('#playlist');
$( playlist ).append( songlist );
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#000000;
}
#playlist{
 float:right;
 width:60%;
 padding:10px;
   background-color:#373636;
 border:dashed #F7060A;
}
.tracklist{
 margin:5px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.songs{
 float:left;
}
.time{
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>playlist12-29.1</title>
<link href="mus_css/playlist12-29.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
        <div id="playlist">
        <!---<li class="tracklist">
    <span class="songs"></span>
    <span class="time"></span>
   </li>--->
        </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="mus_js/playlist12-29.1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solutions works as well. Now I'm not sure which solution will work best. lol

Comment: Thanks. All of these solutions works. Now I'm not sure which solution will work best. lol

Comment: upon further coding none of these work as I need only the 1 track set at a time as it's part of a slide of 6 album covers, album cover names and album tracks. I need to show the 1st set of tracks. ie [0] then onclick, then the next set [1], and so on. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `tl` var to an empty string for each album, then iterate through the song list and `+=` each song to the `tl` before returning it and moving to the next album.

```js
var albumData = [{"imageUrl":"music_imgs/covers/genpx1.png","artist":"Gen1artist","name":"Gen1name","release":"released 2017","tracks":[{"TrackNumber":"1","link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3","song":"Gen1Track1","songimgUrl":"music_imgs/availsound.png","duration":"2:47"},{"TrackNumber":2,"song":"Gen1Track2","duration":"0:00"},{"TrackNumber":3,"link":"media/ffile_example_MP3_700KB.mp3","song":"Gen1Track3","songimgUrl":"music_imgs/availsound.png","duration":"2:52"},{"TrackNumber":4,"link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3","song":"Gen1Track4","songimgUrl":"music_imgs/availsound.png","duration":"3:25"}]},{"imageUrl":"music_imgs/covers/genpx2.png","artist":"Gen2artist","name":"Gen2name","release":"released 201x","tracks":[{"TrackNumber":1,"link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3","song":"Gen2Track1","songimgUrl":"music_imgs/availsound.png","duration":"4:15"},{"TrackNumber":2,"song":"Gen2Track2","duration":"3:22"},{"TrackNumber":3,"song":"Gen2Track3","duration":"3:13"},{"TrackNumber":4,"song":"Gen2Track4","duration":"5:01"}]},{"imageUrl":"music_imgs/covers/genpx3.png","artist":"Gen3artist","name":"Gen3name","release":"released 2014","tracks":[{"TrackNumber":1,"link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3","song":"Gen3Track1","songimgUrl":"music_imgs/availsound.png","duration":"4:04"},{"TrackNumber":2,"song":"Gen3Track2","duration":"0:00"},{"TrackNumber":3,"song":"Gen3Track3","duration":"0:00"},{"TrackNumber":4,"song":"Gen3Track4","duration":"0:00"}]},{"imageUrl":"music_imgs/covers/genpx4.png","artist":"Gen4artist","name":"Gen4name","release":"released 2006","tracks":[{"TrackNumber":1,"link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3","song":"Gen4Track1","songimgUrl":"music_imgs/availsound.png","duration":"3:03"},{"TrackNumber":2,"link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3","song":"Gen4Track2","songimgUrl":"music_imgs/availsound.png","duration":"4:36"},{"TrackNumber":3,"link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3","song":"Gen4Track3","songimgUrl":"music_imgs/availsound.png","duration":"2:52"},{"TrackNumber":4,"song":"Gen4Track4","duration":"0:00"}]}]

let tl

var songlist = $(`${albumData.map(function(songs) {      
    tl = ""
    for (var a in songs.tracks) {
        tl += `
            <li class="songlist">
                <span class="songs">
                    ${songs.tracks[a].TrackNumber + ".&nbsp;" + songs.tracks[a].song}
                </span>
                <span class="time">
                    ${songs.tracks[a].duration}
                </span>
            </li>`
    }
    return tl
}).join('')}`)

var playlist=$('#playlist')

$( playlist ).append( songlist )
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
body{
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#000000;
}
#playlist{
 float:right;
 width:60%;
 padding:10px;
  background-color:#373636;
 border:dashed #F7060A;
}
.songlist{
 margin:5px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.songs{
 float:left;
}
.time{
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="playlist"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solutions works as well. Now I'm not sure which solution will work best. lol

Comment: @mim For large data sets, `for..in` loops are faster than `map()`, but it could also just come down to your personal preference. Whichever you find more readable.